# How to extract a dataset from twitter?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, social-networking, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

Im planning on do my bachelors thesis on machine learning, i was wondering if there is any way to extract a big dataset of tweets in order to use them for my thesis. i know there are several datasets of tweets but i would like to extract one in spanish since there is no one in this language. I all ready try with this script [twitterstream.py](https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment1/twitterstream.py) but i dont get how is the process of obtaining a token and if obtain the token what kind of tweets i will obtain?, i mean do i will obtain only my friend´s tweets?. How´s the process of obtain the dataset?, it seems that im a little bit lost on how to aproach this task.

Comment: Have you read the **twitter API documentation**? Your questions are answered there in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need the access toke to authorize yourself to the twitter API. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens)
Once you done that you can use the Twitter API. Of course if tweets are private you wont be able to see them (unless you are "friends" with the account).

Then i would suggest that you look at the streaming API to find the tweets that you need. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming) As far as i know there is no language Filter for searching the Twitter API, so i would suggest that you need a Filter Classifier for spanish.